# Dependency management for Android projects

Tags: android, dependency-management, nexus

I'm coming from iOS development world and was pretty happy with [CocoaPods](http://www.cocoapods.org) (which is like [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) in the ruby world).

Now on Android development I'm struggling a bit to find something comparable. I just started using Maven successfully and setup a local maven repository with [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), I can easily specify dependencies like `roboguice` without a problem in my project's `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.roboguice</groupId>
        <artifactId>roboguice</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Which is exactly what I want, but here's the catch: How can I add a dependency (= upload an artifact) to my local Nexus repository, which wasn't meant to work with maven in the first place and isn't available via any of the public maven repositories.

I envision something like the podfiles from Cocoapods. These files are lightweight specifications which describes the dependencies I later reference from my project. I suppose I've to write such a specification as custom `pom.xml` for my dependencies but I have no clue how to deploy them afterwards to my local maven repository server (= Nexus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nexus supports manual uploads to hosted repositories that allows you to do just that. Read more about it in the official documentation at http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/using-sect-uploading.html